# Issue in creating bot service in Azure- Error while creating microsoft App id and password

Tags: azure, bots, azure-bot-service

I am trying to create a bot service using Free Trail Subscription in Azure Portal. While clicking on **create Microsoft Appid and Password** button, it directs to a page. Instead of showing me up with name and id in **Generate App ID and password page**,I get the below error as

**"There's a temporary problem with the service. Please try again. If you continue to get this message, try again later"**

Could anyone help me out to resolve this error. Also can you confirm if this is due to when a service is down or issue with the browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue rectified by creating a separate Microsoft account id and by logging in using that I was able to generate appid and password successfully.