# Azure Bot Service Error Message

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I am having a problem trying to create a Microsoft App ID and password for my Bot. After creating a bot on *Bot Service* on the Azure portal I try to create a Microsoft App ID.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UneuA.png - Create_a_Microsoft_App_ID]

When I click the *Create Microsoft App ID and password* button as shown on the image above, it opens a new tab and I get this error message:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWIGw.png - Temporary_problem]

I'm also having problems with a previously created bot. When I go to *All Resources* on the Azure portal and click on that previously created bot I get the following error message:

**Unable to find the specified id**

I thank you in advance for your time and help :)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't post the pictures directly. I just created this account therefore I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: try create the bot, through this url https://dev.botframework.com

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I already tried that. The same problem occurs when creating the Microsoft App Id.

Comment: So, this kinda problem is common. Apparently, it should be a real temporary problem. Should be solved in the near future.

Comment: I really hope so :/

Comment: Is this behavior consistent?  Have you tried reloading the Azure Portal, and click "Create Microsoft App Id and Password" again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely saw this happening on some MSA accounts, it's not a Bot Framework or Azure Bot Service issue. Two things you might try:

1. try creating MSA AppId and Password directly from https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/
2. If this doesn't work, do you have another MSA account you could try with?

Hope this helps
Andrea

Comment: Yep, I tried doing that too :/ No, I only have a free trial account.

Comment: @A_b_pereira_acc, can you please try creating another MSA account here https://signup.live.com/? Then go to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ and create a new MSA AppId and password pair. Far from ideal, but this should work.

Comment: @A_b_pereira_acc this user had the same issue and solved it as I suggested above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540485/issue-in-creating-bot-service-in-azure-error-while-creating-microsoft-app-id-an

Comment: I used another account and it solved the problem. The difference was that my first account was free, I think that is the real problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error before.  Retrying fixed the issue for me (click `Create Microsoft App ID and password` button again).  Please try again.  You might need to sign out, clear your cookies, and sign back in.

Comment: Already tried it. I also tried to click the _Create Microsoft App ID and password_ button on _incognito mode_ and in different browsers (_Google Chrome_ and _Internet Explorer_). The result is always the same

Comment: Yes, I tried it. As suggested above, using another account solved the issue.